# Multiple meteor applications using the same domain in digitalocean using nginx?

Tags: node.js, meteor, nginx, digital-ocean

I'm trying to host 2 applications in the same droplet in digitalocean by using nginx

But so far I've only been able to get the root application running (the one without example.com/secondapp)

I want to be able to not use a subdomain and just use `example.com/secondmeteorapp` to be able to access it.

My `sites-enabled/default` looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        #listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com/;
    #ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle-myApp-domain-com.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myApp_domain_com.key;

    location /dragonfire {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;

        proxy_redirect off;

    }
    location /images {
            alias /home/dragonfire-build/bundle/programs/web.browser/assets/images;
            access_log off;
            expires max;
    }

    location /fonts {
        alias /home/dragonfire-build/bundle/programs/web.browser/assets/images;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    location "^/[a-z0-9]{40}\.(css|js)$" {
        root /home/dragonfire-build/bundle/programs/web.browser;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

}
```

however, when I access `http://serverIpAddress/dragonfire` it can't find the css or javascript giving me this error:
`GET http://myipaddress/1f3848edee9e199050b9b1965b9e697aa714b9f3.css?meteor_css_resource=true`

`GET http://myipaddress/6e48198c6b584ff79c86e0c624a65b4853faaf50.js?meteor_js_resource=true 404 (Not Found)`

I can access the app if I go directly through the IP address and port but not via the nginx way

**QUESTION**

How can I access a second app using the same domain but with a `/mysecondapp` (in this case `/dragonfire` at the end?